# Abort MassTransit StartAsync

Tags: c#, asynchronous, masstransit

In startup phase of the service we start MassTransitClient subscriptions.
Startup runs on background thread.

```
void Startup()
{
 ...
  var busProvider = serviceProvider.Get<IBusProvider>();
  busProviderLaunchTask = busProvider.StartAsync();
  tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
  busProviderLaunchTask.Wait(busProviderTokenSource.Token);
}
```

There is a Stop() method to stop the hosted service where cleanup is done.
Problem is when service being stopped prematurely - startup code hasn't finished - we need to make sure busProvider is stopped.
First problem is that busProvider.StartAsync() hangs for a while - how can it be aborted?
Aborting background thread kind of solves everything - but there are many exceptions from the busProvider. 
Also Stop method's cleanup becomes undeterministic as we don't know what managed to initialize and what not.

Waiting for the whole Start to finish, when we really want to Stop is way too long.
These are hanging:
busProvider.StartAsync()
busProviderLaunchTask.Wait()

As you can see, some attempt to provide CancelationSource is made, but it's all pretty raw.

Any ideas generally?
Specifically, can we shutdown busProvider prematurely?

Comment: Why haven't you made your `Startup` method async so that you can `await` your asynchronous called? A solid rule of thumb is to never call .Wait() on a task. It's a code smell that *most* of the time means you've done something wrong. Sounds like you need to read [Async/Await best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming) before continuing.

Comment: But how will async help if we need to shut down bus, in case Stop was called?

Comment: It may or may not help that, but you need to do it to avoid deadlocks. Read the link I provided you.

Comment: The framework invoking that method is not async. Consider Startup method being invoked from the console Main method.

Comment: Console main methods can be made async.

Comment: It can in later frameworks, but assume it cannot. Point is we need to terminate starting MassTransit client bus prematurely, if user stops the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the cancellation token to `StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)`.

If you cancel the token, it will cancel the `StartAsync` call (it can take a few moments, but it will cancel).

Also, abide by the *async* rules – using that .Wait() will cause all kinds of issues.

You can use `TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.StartAsync(), cancellationToken)`, which awaits a little better than calling .Wait(), it's unfortunate that startup code is often async. That's what bus.Start() does under the covers.

> TaskUtil is part of MassTransit.Util namespace.

Comment: We use MassTransit 1.0.92. StartAsync doesn't have any arguments.

Comment: That isn't even a real version.

Comment: There is however TaskUtil.Await(() => bus.StartAsync(), cancellationToken) overload. Thanks Chris Patterson, will give it a try.

Comment: Well, the version you have isn't MassTransit. They're all here, and even v4 is 2+ years old: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit/

Comment: We may consider upgrading it, but it's always dangerous. Your proposed helper util works like a charm. Thank you, @Chris Patterson

Comment: It's Messaging.MassTransitClient.Transport.BusProvider. Sorry, somewhere I said MassTransit forgetting it's a separate assembly.